# Fish - Get Current Shell Command

Tags: shell, fish

I'm trying to get the current shell command (not `$history[1]` !), specifically i'd like to be able to replace the fish_title - `(pwd)`, with specific running programs i.e. `python` if I'm in interactive shell, `vim` etc.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#other):

> The first argument to fish_title will contain the most recently executed foreground command as a string, starting with fish 2.2.

So a simple

```
function fish_title
  echo $argv (set -q SSH_CONNECTION; and hostname)":" $PWD
end
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, Special Variables

> _, the name of the currently running command.

The default `fish_title` function does this already, does it not?

```
function fish_title
    echo $_ " "
    set -q SSH_CONNECTION; and echo (hostname)":"
    pwd
end
```

Comment: I seem to get incomprehensible results with `$_ ' '` when it comes to the title bar.

Comment: Unlike `$history[1]`  - `$_` doesn't contain arguments, so a number of processes started with sudo will simply show `sudo`.